# Building Plutus-apps on Mac M1

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I am in the 3rd pioneers cohort, going through the env setup. I have Mac M1 with Monterey. I installed nix and added config for the caches etc as recommended here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps#nix-on-macos

When I run "nix-build -A plutus-playground.server", it ends with:

> unpacking source archive
> /private/tmp/nix-build-source.drv-0/f089a6f090cdb35fcf95f865fc6a31ba6b3ac4eb.tar.gz
> error: attribute 'aarch64-darwin' missing
>
> ```
>    at /nix/store/cyfj6bd0n0ckvkm67mhjyg1qcvrfgsg9-source/artifact.nix:11:10:
>
>        10| let
>        11|   host = hosts.${stdenv.targetPlatform.system};
>          |          ^
>        12| (use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
> ```

has anyone managed to build and run the Plutus playground on M1 Mac ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This guide worked to get me past the server build: https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1/blob/main/README.md

Answer (score 3):

We do not currently have native support for `aarch64-darwin` (macOS on Apple Silicon chips). I expect this will come throughout the year. For now please use rosetta2. We also do not have caches for `aarch64-darwin` yet.

Try to pass the system string to nix like so:

```
$ nix-build -A plutus-playground.server --argstr system x86_64-darwin
```

Comment: Hi @angerman, thanks for the answer. I am getting segmentation fault when I run it  with the additional parameter:
unpacking source archive /private/tmp/nix-build-source.drv-0/c8c5e6a6fbb12a73598d1a434984a36e880ce3cf.tar.gz
zsh: segmentation fault  nix-build -A plutus-playground.server --argstr system x86_64-darwin

Comment: Did you by any chance have `sandbox = true` in your nix config?

Answer (score 2):

Apple M1 seems to be supported meanwhile. This finally worked for me:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps
$ cabal update
$ nix-build -A plutus-playground.server
$ nix-build -A plutus-playground.client
$ nix-shell
```

Comment: Any additional nix configs especially for mac/m1 needed before you ran these commands @Dirk?