# Bad File Descriptor on nix-build of Plutus-Apps on Mac M1

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, nix, plutus-starter

I am seeing an error building Plutus-Apps on Mac M1.

After precisely following

https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1/blob/main/README.md

UPDATE: This did resolve. These errors appears to be due to corrupted cache in nix store from download on in the cache itself.

as recommended here:

[Building Plutus-apps on Mac M1](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6269/building-plutus-apps-on-mac-m1)

I get an Invalid File Descriptor error. Here are the logs

```
 copying path '/nix/store/lkbwcc0zyq9jzz8mk149rmfxw6ycl627-curl-7.81.0-dev' from  'https://hydra.iohk.io'...
 building '/nix/store/9z2bhjz6slfphlm4xbpkh9c0hzll46kh-source.drv'...

 ErrorErrorxexecuting '/nix/store/067f780bk90ghn7yhz914d5fykmll7a4-bash-5.1-p16/bin/bash': Bad file descriptor
 error: builder for '/nix/store/9z2bhjz6slfphlm4xbpkh9c0hzll46kh-source.drv' failed with exit code 1;
   last 2 log lines:
   > 
   > ErrorErrorxexecuting '/nix/store/067f780bk90ghn7yhz914d5fykmll7a4-bash-5.1-p16/bin/bash': Bad file descriptor
   For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/9z2bhjz6slfphlm4xbpkh9c0hzll46kh-source.drv'.
 (use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

here is full logs:

```
    nix log /nix/store/9z2bhjz6slfphlm4xbpkh9c0hzll46kh-source.drv
 ^A
 ^E^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Error^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^E^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Error^@^@^@x^@^@^@^@^@^@^@executing '/nix/store/067f780bk90ghn7yhz914d5fyk>
lines 1-2/2 (END)
```

Here is logs with full trace:

```
 deano@Ds-MacBook-Pro plutus-apps % nix-build --show-trace -A plutus- playground.server                         
 building '/nix/store/9z2bhjz6slfphlm4xbpkh9c0hzll46kh-source.drv'...

 ErrorErrorxexecuting '/nix/store/067f780bk90ghn7yhz914d5fykmll7a4-bash-5.1-p16/bin/bash': Bad file descriptor
 error: builder for '/nix/store/9z2bhjz6slfphlm4xbpkh9c0hzll46kh-source.drv' failed  with exit code 1;
   last 2 log lines:
   > 
   > ErrorErrorxexecuting '/nix/store/067f780bk90ghn7yhz914d5fykmll7a4-bash-5.1- p16/bin/bash': Bad file descriptor
   For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/9z2bhjz6slfphlm4xbpkh9c0hzll46kh-source.drv'.

    … while realising the context of path  '/nix/store/dv269kw7fp6y81n0k20w9s4a05s2z4f7-source'

   at /Users/deano/plutus/plutus-apps/default.nix:13:16:

       12| , sources ? import ./nix/sources.nix { inherit system; } //  sourcesOverride
       13| , haskellNix ? import sources.haskell-nix {
         |                ^
       14|     pkgs = import sources.nixpkgs { inherit system; };

   … while evaluating 'throwIfNot'

   at /nix/store/m2vv0bxfchzrjngx8wi0i7dhzb9q2g50-source/lib/trivial.nix:379:22:

      378|   */
      379|   throwIfNot = cond: msg: if cond then x: x else throw msg;
         |                      ^
      380|

   … from call site

   at /nix/store/m2vv0bxfchzrjngx8wi0i7dhzb9q2g50-source/pkgs/top-  level/default.nix:55:5:

       54|   checked =
       55|     throwIfNot (lib.isList overlays) "The overlays argument to nixpkgs   must be a list."
         |     ^
       56|     lib.foldr (x: throwIfNot (lib.isFunction x) "All overlays passed to nixpkgs must be functions.") (r: r) overlays

   … while evaluating anonymous lambda

   at /nix/store/m2vv0bxfchzrjngx8wi0i7dhzb9q2g50-source/pkgs/top-level/default.nix:19:1:

       18|
       19| { # The system packages will be built on. See the manual for the
         | ^
       20|   # subtle division of labor between these two `*System`s and the three

   … from call site

   at /nix/store/m2vv0bxfchzrjngx8wi0i7dhzb9q2g50-source/pkgs/top-   level/impure.nix:82:1:

       81|
       82| import ./. (builtins.removeAttrs args [ "system" ] // {
         | ^
       83|   inherit config overlays localSystem;

   … while evaluating anonymous lambda

   at /nix/store/m2vv0bxfchzrjngx8wi0i7dhzb9q2g50-source/pkgs/top- level/impure.nix:14:1:

       13|
       14| { # We put legacy `system` into `localSystem`, if `localSystem` was not   passed.
         | ^
       15|   # If neither is passed, assume we are building packages on the current

   … from call site

   at /Users/deano/plutus/plutus-apps/nix/default.nix:30:10:

       29|
       30|   pkgs = import sources.nixpkgs {
         |          ^
       31|     inherit crossSystem;

   … while evaluating the attribute 'pkgs'

   at /Users/deano/plutus/plutus-apps/nix/default.nix:44:10:

       43| {
       44|   inherit pkgs plutus-apps sources;
         |          ^
       45| }
```

And here is nix.conf

```
% cat /etc/nix/nix.conf

 build-users-group = nixbld
 substituters        = https://hydra.iohk.io    https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
 trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ=  iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=

 system = x86_64-darwin
 extra-platforms = x86_64-darwin aarch64-darwin

 sandbox = false
 extra-sandbox-paths = /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /usr/lib /private/tmp /private/var/tmp /usr/bin/env
 experimental-features = nix-command
 extra-experimental-features = flakes
```

I tried increasing file limits ..

```
launchctl limit maxfiles
maxfiles    200000         200000
```

But still get the error.

Comment: I did install GCH separately before but I don't think that should be a factor in running nix-shell or nix build

Comment: No it does not affect at all because GHC comes with Nix. When you enter a in a shell you already have access to all plutus dependencies.

Comment: [60 of 60] Compiling Blockfrost.API   ( src/Blockfrost/API.hs, dist/build/Blockfrost/API.o, dist/build/Blockfrost/API.dyn_o )
 error: builder for '/nix/store/zx91r06dgsdddrmd1gzpx2ckiaw9qf29-blockfrost-api-lib-blockfrost-api-0.3.1.0.drv' failed with exit code 1;
   last 10 log lines:
   > [51 of 60] Compiling Blockfrost.API.Cardano.Assets ( src/Blockfrost/API/Cardano/Assets.hs, dist/build/Blockfrost/API/Cardano/Assets.o, dist/build/Blockfrost/API/Cardano/Assets.dyn_o )

Comment: both  server and client compile ok now. I suspect that was corrupted download of cache or corrupted cache.  But now I get above error during nix-shell run

Comment: I think these errors are from corrupt download of cache but not sure.

Comment: I ran nix-shell again but keep getting the compile error with Blockfront API

Comment: detail logs shows: location info>: error: <command line>: dlopen(/nix/store/3g1j67mmalbr40mryf53a67ip3kj17i3-blockfrost-api-lib-blockfrost-api-0.3.1.0-config/lib/links/libHScontainers-0.6.2.1-ghc8.10.4.20210212.dylib, 0x0005): cannot dlopen > [43 of 60] Compiling Blockfrost.Util.Pagination

Comment: ok, got passed this error of dlopen by rerunning nix-shell in another terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try to follow the guide for Mac M1 here:

https://plutus-community.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#Environment/Build/Mac_M1/

Comment: I am following that. And the errors above are not now appearing.  The nix-build of server and client worked ok after rerunning a few times. However the step of running nix-shell is now giving an error.

Comment: error is [60 of 60] Compiling Blockfrost.API   ( src/Blockfrost/API.hs, dist/build/Blockfrost/API.o, dist/build/Blockfrost/API.dyn_o )
 error: builder for '/nix/store/zx91r06dgsdddrmd1gzpx2ckiaw9qf29-blockfrost-api-lib-blockfrost-api-0.3.1.0.drv' failed with exit code 1;
   last 10 log lines:
   > [51 of 60] Compiling Blockfrost.API.Cardano.Assets ( src/Blockfrost/API/Cardano/Assets.hs, dist/build/Blockfrost/API/Cardano/Assets.o, dist/build/Blockfrost/API/Cardano/Assets.dyn_o )

Comment: The previous errors with file descriptors I suspect are from corrupt download of cache or corrupt cache.

Comment: 60 of 60] Compiling Blockfrost.API   ( src/Blockfrost/API.hs, dist/build/Blockfrost/API.o, dist/build/Blockfrost/API.dyn_o )
error: builder for '/nix/store/zx91r06dgsdddrmd1gzpx2ckiaw9qf29-blockfrost-api-lib-blockfrost-api-0.3.1.0.drv' failed with exit code 1;
       last 10 log lines:

Comment: > [60 of 60] Compiling Blockfrost.API   ( src/Blockfrost/API.hs, dist/build/Blockfrost/API.o, dist/build/Blockfrost/API.dyn_o )
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/zx91r06dgsdddrmd1gzpx2ckiaw9qf29-blockfrost-api-lib-blockfrost-api-0.3.1.0.drv'.
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/a45kgfid8c37ika0bx6f6dy6hrlya168-blockfrost-client-core-lib-blockfrost-client-core-0.2.0.0-config.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/j7rszs8r90643v61cv430fp21z8n9456-blockfrost-client-core-lib-blockfrost-client-core-0.2.0.0.drv' failed to build

Comment: sorry to post log here but I could not update the question at this time.

Comment: detail logs shows: location info>: error:
    <command line>: dlopen(/nix/store/3g1j67mmalbr40mryf53a67ip3kj17i3-blockfrost-api-lib-blockfrost-api-0.3.1.0-config/lib/links/libHScontainers-0.6.2.1-ghc8.10.4.20210212.dylib, 0x0005): cannot dlopen >
[43 of 60] Compiling Blockfrost.Util.Pagination ( src/Blockfrost/Util/Pagination.hs, dist/build/Blockfrost/Util/Pagination.o, dist/build/Blockfrost/Util/Pagination.dyn_o )
[44 of 60] Compiling Blockfrost.Util.Sorting ( src/Blockfrost/Util/Sorting.hs, dist/build/Blockfrost/Util/Sorting.o, dist/build/Blockfrost/Util/Sorting.dyn_o )

Comment: I tried running nix-shell again but same result. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: got passed this error by rerunning nix-shell in another terminal. It must have been a resource limit of some type.